# Broken AVD system path. Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT value [c:\android-sdk]

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device, avd-manager

I'm using Android Studio for Windows.

When I try to run Android Emulator, gives a panic, "Broken AVD system path. Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT value [c:\android-sdk]" (c:\android-sdk) is where my sdk is correctly installed and Android Studio sees as installed.

- I reinstalled my sdk, didn't work.
- I uninstalled and reinstalled 2 times Android Studio, nothing changed.
- I uninstalled and reinstalled emulator from sdk manager, nothing changed.
- I deleted android user and system variables, Android Studio started look for them.

In another computers without having user variables, it works normally. It used to work before, I didn't change anything deliberately.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I found out the solution.

.android directory is under my home account and the path contains non ascii characters, I just moved it under sdk directory and set ANDROID_SDK_ROOT value to c:\android-sdk.android and it works now.

Comment: dude this is right.  Thanks.  Not very straight forward but with a little searching and reference to how you move .android to your android sdk folder helps.

Answer (score 0):

ANDROID_AVD_HOME and ANDROID_EMULATOR_HOME are must be under ANDROID_SDK_ROOT directory.

Then restart computer and create new virtual device.

[image]